# How to restore JSON stored in database to <MyClass> object

Tags: java, android, json, database, adapter

I've got SQLite database in my current android project with TEXT columns that represent JSON objects converted from my own Java classes. Like this:

```
String myClassInJsonString = gson.toJson(MyJavaClass.class)
```

Gson class allows me to use `.fromJson(string, objectType)` method to convert JSON String stored in my database back to my original class with all getters and setters.

My question:
 Is there any way to save my class from database back to original Class type so I could use its getters and get a concrete value of the object?

I can use this, but I don't want the (long) JSON strings to be loaded to xml TextViews or any Views. I'd like to load it back to the original class type, then use some getter and get a value I want to show in TextView.

```
String[] from = {Provider.MyClass.FIRST_COLUM, Provider.MyClass.SECOND_COLUMN }; 
int[] to = {R.id.textID_1, R.id.textID_2};  

this.simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, null, from, to, Defaults.NO_FLAGS);
```

Should I use any (own) Adapter, but not SimpleCursorAdapter?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change the column type from TEXT to BLOB and used this code to get list of my entity.

```
public List<Entity> getAllEntities(String tableName, String column) {
            List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT " + column
                    + " FROM " + tableName;

            EntitiesDatabaseOpenHelper openHelper = new EntitiesDatabaseOpenHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase database = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    byte[] entityBlob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(column));
                    String json = new String(entityBlob);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Entity entity = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Entity>() {
                    }.getType());
                    entities.add(entity);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            return entities;
        }
```

This is not a very lucky solution. I found a way to store data of each entity in tables that every entity parameter is saved in a single column. Then I can use joins and own Adapter to display the data.